# loading and saving comboBox text to .txt

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I'm writing a script where I can load/save the text in all comboBoxes in a windows form. Here's the working method I'm using to save the comboBox.Text to a `.txt` file:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
        // clear previous input curve values
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\inCurves.txt", String.Empty);
        objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\inCurves.txt", true); // true wil make program add new lines 
        // some combobox voodoo
        var combBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("comboBox"));
        foreach (var cmbBox in combBoxes)
        {
            objWriter.Write(cmbBox.Text);
            objWriter.Write("*");
        }
        objWriter.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Curve Names Successfully saved in C: Users Public inCurves.txt", "You Saved Your Curve Names ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Saving Curve names \n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Here's the method I'm using to Load saved comboBox information from the .txt.

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string CurveNamesInText = "";
        char[] delimiter = { '*' };
        CurveNamesInText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\inCurves.txt");
        string[] crvIn = CurveNamesInText.Split(delimiter);
        string BottomDepth = crvIn[0];
        string TopDepth = crvIn[1];
        var combBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("comboBox")).ToList();
        for (int i=0; i < combBoxes.Count; i++ )
        {
            combBoxes[i].Text= crvIn[i];
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Loading Curve names \n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

These two methods work for a windows form with 8 comboBoxes, but does not seem to work for a windows form with 70+ comboBoxes.

Any suggestions as to why? Is there a limit to objWriter? the `.txt` has one line but each text field (from comboBoxes) are delimited by the `*` character.

Comment: No, there's no limit to the stream writer.  Certainly not such a small limit.  How exactly is this failing?  What "does not seem to work" about it?

Comment: I figured there was no limit. Nothing is being populated in the inCurves.txt, nor am I receiving an error message....

Comment: What happens when you debug?  Does it try to write to the file?  Does the loop iterate the expected number of times?  Is the stream closed?

Comment: Please define what happens when it "does not seem to work for a windows form with 70+ comboBoxes"... what does not seem to work? Writing to the text file, getting all the combo boxes? ...

Comment: I've since rebuilt the App and now this function works. Thanks for your help